# Error 257 when opening file by tapping it in files app. Acessing the same file via the file browser works (Swift 5 - Xcode12)

Tags: ios, swift, icloud-drive

When I tap a file my app supports in the iOS file manger, my apps delegate method

`private func open(url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]?)->Bool`

gets called, where I read the file

```
do {
        try fileData = Data(contentsOf: url)
}
catch { 
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

which gives an error 257 (not authorised).
When accessing the same file using the document picker :

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt URL: URL) {
 if controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.import {
    var fileData : Data
    do {
         try fileData = Data(contentsOf: URL)
    }
    catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

everything works fine. I get a data object which I can use. One thing I noticed is that the AppDelegate method gets an URL in the form of

```
/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads/filename
```

while the documentPicker callback gets

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A30D4D7-BD7D-4051-B3DE-143E18F48B23/tmp/myAppIndentifier-Inbox/filename
```

Adding - as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596871/no-permission-to-read-icloud-drive-file) -

```
let result  = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

did not make a difference. My "Supports opening documents in place" plist key is set to TRUE. Anyone any idea?